# How do I fix this error loading an ontology in owlready2

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owlready

I am trying to load the ontology but I get an error that you can see in the post, the code is shown below.

Code:

```
from owlready2 import * 
import os
onto = get_ontology("file://C:/Users/achev/Documents/Carro.owl") 
onto.load() 
n_classes = len(list(onto.classes()))
print(n_classes)
```

Error:

```
File "c:/Users/achev/Desktop/Proyecto de grado/Python/prueba.py", line 4, in <module>
    onto = get_ontology("file://C:/Users/achev/Documents/Carro.owl").load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 810, in load
    if self.world.graph.indexed: self._load_properties()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owlready2\namespace.py", line 849, in _load_properties
    raise TypeError("'%s' belongs to more than one entity types (cannot be both a property and a class/an individual)!" % Prop.iri)
```

Comment: and not showing the code you used makes the stacktrace useless ...

Comment: Hey @Erick. Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is very hard to help you from the information you've given in your post. Could you please give a bit more detail about what you are trying to do, and what does not work?

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to respond, post edited with the necessary information @Jober

Comment: Please show us your owl ontology (or at least the part of it which the error is due to)